# How to create dynamically input fields based on fetched data

Tags: javascript, html, json

What I want to achieve:

Have input fields created based on my JSON file. My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "main_object": {
        "id": "new",
        "getExerciseTitle": "Test",
        "language": "nl_NL",
        "application": "lettergrepen",
        "main_object": {
            "title": "Test",
            "language": "nl_NL",
            "exercises": [
                {
                    "word": "test1",
                    "syllables": [
                        "test",
                        "ikels"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "word": "test2",
                    "syllables": [
                        "test",
                        "ikels",
                        "example3"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "word": "test3",
                    "syllables": [
                        "test",
                        "ikels"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "dataType": "json"
    }
}
```

so to clarify: I have 2 syllables in test1, I want to have 2 input fields next to the word test1. test2 has 3 syllables and therefore I want 3 syllables next to my word test2 (hope this clarified enough). This is what I have right now as code, but I wouldn't know how to target the word so the `syllables`will only append in the same row as the word is placed in. I did find something about `syllables.join(' ')`, but i'm not entirely sure whether this is correct or not.

```
var fakejson = { // extrapolating this based on the code
    main_object: {
        main_object: {
            exercises: [
                {
                    word: "one"
                },
                {
                    word: "two"
                },
                {
                    word: "three"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

function createExercise(json) {
    const exercises = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;
    exercises.forEach(function (exercise) {
        var exer = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'row'
        })
            .append(
                $('<div/>', {
                    'class': 'col-md-3'
                })
                    .append(
                        $('<div/>', {
                            'class': 'row'
                        })
                            .append($('<div>', {
                                class: 'col-md-3 audioButton'
                            }))
                            .append($('<div>', {
                                class: 'col-md-9 ExerciseWordFontSize exerciseWord',
                                'id': 'wordInput[' + ID123 + ']',
                                text: exercise.word
                            }))
                    )
            ).append(
                $('<div>', {
                    class: 'col-md-9'
                })
                    .append(
                        $('<div/>', {
                            class: 'row'
                        }))
                    .append($('<div/>', {
                        class: 'col-md-3 inputSyllables'
                    }))
            );

        $("#exerciseField").append(exer);
        ID123++;
        exer.find('.audioButton').append(getAudioForWords());
        exer.find('.inputSyllables').append(inputFieldsForSyllables());
    });

}

createExercise(fakejson);

function inputFieldsForSyllables() {
    var getInputField = $('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'class': 'form-group form-control col-md-3',
        'name': 'inputSyllables'
    });
    return getInputField;
}


function getAudioForWords() {
    var audioBtn = $('<button/>', {
        'class': 'btn btn-primary fa fa-volume-up sound'
    });
    return audioBtn;
}
```

as you can see I do have a `forEach` loop, but I am not entirely sure if I could create the inputs with the same loop. I would rather not have the `syllables`shown in the front end at all, or else I will have to make them `hidden`, but if not mistaken they will remain in the "Inspect Elements".
a picture to clarify for you what I mean: [image]

as you can see they have their own rows. So I the syllables won't be mixed, but will stay in the row of their `word`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code,

var obj = {
            "main_object": {
                "id": "new",
                "getExerciseTitle": "Test",
                "language": "nl_NL",
                "application": "lettergrepen",
                "main_object": {
                  "title": "Test",
                  "language": "nl_NL",
                  "exercises": [
                    {
                      "word": "test1",
                      "syllables": [
                        "test",
                        "ikels"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "word": "test2",
                      "syllables": [
                        "test",
                        "ikels",
                        "example3"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "word": "test3",
                      "syllables": [
                        "test",
                        "ikels"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "dataType": "json"
            }
        };

```
    var exe_array = obj.main_object.main_object.exercises;
    exe_array.forEach(function(val, key){
        var row_element = document.createElement('div');
        row_element.className = 'row';
        var col_element = document.createElement('div');
        col_element.className = 'col-md-3';
        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val.word));
        col_element.appendChild(label);
        var syllables_arr = val.syllables;
        syllables_arr.forEach(function(value) {
            var node = document.createElement('input');
            node.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            node.setAttribute('name', value);
            node.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
            node.setAttribute('value', value);
            col_element.appendChild(node);
            row_element.appendChild(col_element);
            document.body.appendChild(row_element); 
        })
    });
```

Comment: should I replace certain code for ur code or just add ? and the data will never be the same basically. it could be editted by a moderator for example